# How to set the page settings with puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

When performing some actions, chrome sometimes requires the user's permission. How can I accept these popups with puppeteer (In my case "Download multiple files")?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I managed to set `allow-multiple-dowlnoad` setting https://stackoverflow.com/a/73164259/14085862 you may find it helpful for others setting, but it is trail-and-error process & there isn't straight forward way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is currently not-supported and doesn't appear to be in the near future. [According to this ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925), it's apparently not an easy task that's going to be taken on soon.

You might look into using xvbf on "headful" Chrome as opposed to using headless as that appears to be the flag that causes Chrome to not use user-settings.