# Puppeteer chrome allow multiple file download

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, download, chromium, puppeteer

I am trying scrape one site will multiple pdf files. But after downloading the first one, chrome asks me to allow the site to download multiple files.
[image: Download multiple files]

Can we allow this while launching the browser? This is the code which works once I allow manually and downloads all the files.

```
for(selector of selectors){
   await this.currentPage._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: downloadFilePath });
   await this.currentPage.waitFor(1000);
   await this.currentPage.evaluate(el => el.click(), selector);
   await this.currentPage.waitFor(1000 * 20);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

to avoid the allow multiple download popup use following code :

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './'});
```

The downloadPath is the path where you want to download the files.
You need to do it for each page you open.

Comment: this doesn't work in the latest version of puppeteer. `page._client` is not function.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 Update**: `page._client` method has been removed in the latest version of the puppeteer. (I am using `15.x`

I manage to set custom download path & override `allow-multiple-download` popup using `puppeteer-extra` with `puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences` plugin.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra")
const UserPreferencesPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences");

const downloadImageDirectoryPath = process.cwd();

puppeteer.use(
  UserPreferencesPlugin({
    userPrefs: {
      download: {
       // this one handle first time downlaod popup
        prompt_for_download: false,
        open_pdf_in_system_reader: true,
        default_directory: downloadImageDirectoryPath,
        // this arg handle multiple download popup
        automatic_downloads: 1,
      },
      plugins: {
        always_open_pdf_externally: true,
      },
    },
  })
);
```

**Update a week later** above snippet was working but unreliable so I updated my code to below snippet, no issues so far.

```js
puppeteer.use(
  UserPreferencesPlugin({
    userPrefs: {
      download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        open_pdf_in_system_reader: true,
        default_directory: downloadImageDirectoryPath,
        // automatic_downloads: 1,
      },
      plugins: {
        always_open_pdf_externally: true,
      },
      // disable allow-multiple-downloads popup
      profile: {
        default_content_setting_values: {
          automatic_downloads: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code needs a slight tweak and it should work:

```
    await this.currentPage._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: downloadFilePath });
```

Try changing this to

```
    await this.currentPage._client().send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: downloadFilePath });
```

This should hopefully resolve the issue for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.