# Info: Set download file directory path

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

What is the right way to set the download directory path using webdrivermanager?
ref:

`chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);`
Thanks.

Comment: What does the documentation suggest?

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73164259/14085862 for idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the folder in which [WebDriverManager](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) downloads drivers (e.g., chromedriver), it would be as follows:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().cachePath("/path/to/my/folder").setup();
```