# Python: How to set a custom webdriver download path for the built-in Selenium Manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, seleniummanager

How to set a custom webdriver download path for the built-in Selenium Manager?
Unlike other third-party driver managers, there is very little documentation available for this, and I could not find any related discussion anywhere.

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`

Does the WebDriver object have the driver-path data in it which can be extracted?
`<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="8cc15b28be77b3773576ef8b373be420")>`

Comment: If this helps - [Selenium Manager (Beta)](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/)

Answer (score 2):

[webdriver.Chrome](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py) has an optional `service` parameter

```
def __init__(self, options: Options = None, service: Service = None, keep_alive: bool = True):

    service = service if service else Service()
    options = options if options else Options()

    super().__init__(...)
```

If it's `None` it creates a default [Service](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py)

```
class Service(service.ChromiumService):

    def __init__(self, executable_path=None, ...):
        super().__init__(executable_path=executable_path, ...)
```

You can fill it with your own `Service`

```
webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path=driver_executable_path), options=options)
```

Comment: Thank you for the details, but i was asking something else here. the `executable_path` argument above is used when you already have the webdriver downloaded in that folder. I want to know if there is a way to tell Selenium Manager to set the driver download directory to some other folder (possibly inside the project folder, instead of the .cache in Users directory. For reference, when we use webdriver_manager, we can provide `path` argumenet with the desired download path. `chrome_Service(ChromeDriverManager(path = "./Drivers", cache_valid_range=10).install())`

Comment: Nevermind, I went through the selenium package code and found the answer:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.driver_finder import DriverFinder
chrome_options = Options()
driver_path = DriverFinder.get_path(Service(), chrome_options)`

This gives you the download path as `C:\Users\xxxxxx\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\114.0.5735.90\chromedriver.exe`

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for!

- Below code uses the `chromedriver.exe` from the path provided in `Service` class

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service('C:\Backup\Selenium jars\drivers\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe') # chromedriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

- Below code uses the `chromedriver.exe` which is downloaded/managed by `SeleniumManager`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

`SeleniumManager` will look for/ or download the `chromedriver.exe` in below path:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To pass in an `executable_path`, you can use the `service` arg.

Here's an example for **Chrome**:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="./chromedriver")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Here's an example for **Firefox**:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER")
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

You no longer need to specify an `executable_path` due to a fully operational Selenium Manager in `4.11.2`, so this is all you need:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Here's one with the placeholders for options / preferences:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR Answer

Set the environment variable `SE_CACHE_PATH` to the desired drivers path: `os.environ["SE_CACHE_PATH"] = "/path/to/my/drivers/folder"`

#### Complete Answer

You will need to modify the cache directory for Selenium Manager if you want to alter the location from which it downloads drivers. As far as I can tell, nothing is as nice as WebDriveManager as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68220500/13642249), which conveniently sets the path. The rust executable for [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) is wrapped in the `selenium_manager.py` file. The feature to change the default cache directory was [requested in a PR](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/12514) that was merged soon after this question was posted.
Other than editing the source code for `selenium_manager.py` to add the *--cache-path* flag to the `args` [variable](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/8fee675e1e97256bfdea068cbbafba474fe97099/py/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py#L81) with the path following, there is no convenient way to change the cache directory with an exposed method/function at this time. The environment variable `SE_CACHE_PATH` should be set as shown below for the best method:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DRIVERS_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "drivers"
DRIVERS_DIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

os.environ["SE_CACHE_PATH"] = DRIVERS_DIR.name
        
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked me so I went into the package code and finally figure out the solution. Hope this will help someone.

```py
from webdriver_manager.core.driver_cache import DriverCacheManager

driver_path = r"C:\MyPath"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(cache_manager=DriverCacheManager(driver_path)).install()), options=options)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).