# Selenium 4.11.0 error - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

As I understand, with Selenium 4.11.0, the System.setProperty( ) statements are not needed when instantiating the 'webdriver'.  After I removed these statements, the error "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property" is still shown.

The existing answers do not refer to this version of Selenium.  Can someone please explain what's happening? :)  What is the resolution?

Added the following info on 12/26/23:
I double-checked - there are no conflicting versions of Selenium.  The project is configured on Windows 11 OS, with all libs that came with Selenium 4.11.0.

The code is:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

When the code is executed, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/ :  If you are using the latest version of Selenium and you are getting an error, please [turn on logging](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/logging/) and [file a bug report](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues) with that information.

Comment: Please add you code here, also tag the question with the coding language

Comment: Are you sure you don't have conflicting versions of Selenium? Double check the version in your environment. Also, update your question with the code that is showing your error; you have only posted code from someone else with no error, so it is difficult to help.

Comment: How have you attempted this before? Are you trying to set a path yourself? I am not sure if explicitly stating path with environment variables will help like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77302769/13642249), but this answer is in python...

Comment: I just moved from older version of Selenium - which required the path to be set - to this version. I just removed code that used to set the path of the driver and was experimenting.  The whole idea in Selenium 4.11 is that it is not required to set the path - right?

Comment: Hi,
You should mention the OS version and test environment as well that might help. As of versions 4.6 and above you don't need to set the path and the web driver is installed automatically. However, if it does exist in the path it is used over the default download. So if you are running it on a system that already sets the path or a part of a build of a bigger software it might be doing so. You can check by printing the path. Additionally, any reason why you aren't using the latest version? Issues like this may have already been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have either been misled or misunderstood what is happening.

Selenium in order to work properly needs to:

1. Have a local copy of a driver binary. Being a binary, this is different for each OS **and** each browser **and** browser version.
2. Know where this binary is located on your system.

There are several options available to satisfy the above **two** points:

1. Download the correct binary manually and place it somewhere on your system `PATH`.
2. Download the correct binary manually and set a specific property pointing to the binary. The exact property is different for each browser.
3. Use one of the *many* driver managers available out there, which download the binary and set the correct property for you. Use Google to find them.
4. Use the preferred driver manger. This is essentially same as #3.

Note: All of this is independent of the **browser binary**, which must be on the system `PATH` in all cases!

Additional reading for you:

- [Unable to Locate Driver Error](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/)
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Comment: Thanks - but you (probably) are referring to the path of the Chrome binary.  The "IllegalStateException" thrown for me (see my recent edit in the question) refers to the path of the driver.

Comment: @SP Both the browser binary **and** the matching driver binary must be on the `PATH`, if you do not want to use the system property. I updated my answer to clarify this.